# Spring - RESTful provide different entity representations

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, jpa

In advance, I'm not speaking of `Content Negotiation`. Let's assume I've a simple JPA entity, by the way it is convertible with a related DTO it doesn't matter.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    ...
    private String email;
    private String password;
    ...
}
```

I've a RESTful controller with two different routes, a secured one and a public one.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    ...

    @GetMapping("/public")
    private User publicRoute() {

        return service.getLatestUser();
    }

    @Secured("...")
    @GetMapping("/private")
    private User privateRoute() {

        return service.getLatestUser();
    }
}
```

For both routes the same entity is returned, but in the first case a public representation, let's say for a user profile, without sensitive stuff like **E-Mail** and **Password** should be returned. However in the second case a private representation, let's say for the owner itself, is required.

Is there any elegant way for doing this? I tried it on JSON level with `@JsonIgnore` but it doesn't worked for me. Also I tried to use `Response`-Objects, but it results in a lot of boilerplate code! Any suggestions?

**See Also:**
Recommended by [Ananthapadmanabhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7887516/ananthapadmanabhan) there already exists some questions/resources about this topic:

- [Spring REST webservice serializing to multiple JSON formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309557/spring-rest-webservice-serializing-to-multiple-json-formats)
- [How do I serialize using two different getters based on JsonView in RestController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912512/how-do-i-serialize-using-two-different-getters-based-on-jsonview-in-restcontroll/55914779#55914779)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have different DTO objects being returned from the two endpoints instead of returning the same Entity class, that way you can have control over which attributes should be there in the response.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174516/rest-api-dtos-or-not#36175349) about the **advantages of using a DTO** .

Another approach that you could make is to have custom serializers and deserializers for your endpoint.
You could read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309557/spring-rest-webservice-serializing-to-multiple-json-formats) for more details.
And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912512/how-do-i-serialize-using-two-different-getters-based-on-jsonview-in-restcontroll/55914779#55914779)

Comment: Excellent answer thanks... The DTO variant seems to bring more flexibility in design. But I've to write a lot of boilerplate code, for Example a `PublicUserDTO` and a `PrivateUserDTO`. Do you recommend to combine DTO and `@JsonView`, like one DTO class called `UserDTO` for abstraction combined with `@JsonView` for distinguishing between public and private?

Comment: You can implement it any way as you see fit, there are also third party libraries available to reduce the effort taken to convert entity to dto like map-struct. : https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct

Answer (score 0):

## Ignore dto fields while sending back to controller.

you can write you own method if your object is not final 
private User ignoreEmailAndPass(User user){User usr=new User();usr.setName();//send only required fields.}

Answer (score 0):

from Question:

1. In the database table you can have two roles
2. Say like User and Owner 
   3.In the service,check if it is user or owner and get the required details then have the 
   two DTOs,for each of their information that you want to send,set the info and return.
3. Or have a Common DTO, conataining all the information and when want to send user info just ignore the other info{Subset} else all.

Tell me what do you think of this solution?